# What is Announcer badge?

Tags: support

It says : *Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses.*

I could understand it as follows:

I answer or comment to a question by putting a link to another old question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses.

Is this correct?

And what is the difference between 25 views and 25 unique IP addresses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite. When you click the share link under a post, it gives you a user-specific URL. If one of your URLs is visited by clients on 25 or more unique legal IP addresses, you get the badge.

Any by unique IP, I mean when I connect to the internet, I'm given an IP address. Your next door neighbour will have a different IP (assuming they're on a different connection).

Comment: If I review someone else question everyday, does it add +1 to "viewed" ?

Comment: @kamil yes, AFAIK